# I want to capture the full page screenshot from figma design and validate that screen shot with actual static site

Tags: playwright

I want to capture the full page screenshot from figma design and validate that screen shot with actual static site. I need to do that using Playwright visual validation.
I am trying to capture the full page SS of the figma design using below code:

```
test('figma design',async({page})=>
{
await page.goto("https:xyz");
await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot("FigmaDesignScreenshotFull.png",{fullPage: true});
 
});
```

Its runs correctly but its not capturing the full page screenshot its just capturing the page displayed in Figma Url.

Actions taken:-
1- Tried increasing the port size while capturing the screen.
2- Tried scrolling down with mouse and capture
above approach did not worked.

Note:- The Figma design is for responsive site.

Comment: You've left a problem statement/work order, but haven't shared a code attempt or asked a technical question about that attempt, so this appears to be off topic. Please share a [mcve] if you'd like help with this. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Please check the updated question and do share your response on this.

Comment: Thanks but `"https:xyz"` is not a website, so this isn't runnable or reproducible.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes its not a website...this is for example. 
Considering it as a Figma design page URl-(Which cannot be shared).
This is to know whether we can take Screen shots of a figma page or not?
This is my best way i can explain...i hope you will be able to understand, if not please ignore